# How to change tab item color in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabview

I need my tabItem to be purple when active. Just like that:

[image: tabview]

Here's code sample:

```swift
// *some view*
.tabItem {
   Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
   Text("Задания")
}
```

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.accentColor(.purple)` right after the `TabView` closure

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
.tabItem {
   Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
   Text("Задания")
}.accentColor(.orange)
```